# Measure time until an std::future object becomes available

Tags: c++, c++11, std-future

I am trying to measure the duration of an API call which returns an `std::future` object.

My current approach looks like this:

```
std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point endTime, startTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

std::shared_future<API::response> responseFuture = API::request();

std::future_status status = responseFuture.wait_for(3s); // Some Timeout

if (status == std::future_status::ready)
  endTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
else
  // error handling
```

However, I'm unsure about the use of `std::future::wait_for`. [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_future) states:

> This function may block for longer than timeout_duration due to scheduling or resource contention delays.

I am not worried about blocking longer than timeout_duration, but I do require `wait_for` to immediately return once the `std::future` object is available, i.e. not having an implementation along the lines of

```
while(!ready){
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(10ms);
}
```

Is this guaranteed?

Answer (score 2):

The function will return once the shared state is ready, or the timeout (plus a bit) elapses.  Per [futures.unique.future]/21 the effect of the function is

> None if the shared state contains a deferred function ([futures.async]), otherwise **blocks until the shared state is ready** or until the relative timeout ([thread.req.timing]) specified by rel_­time has expired.

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

And [[thread.req.timing]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/thread.req.timing) has

> 2. Implementations necessarily have some delay in returning from a timeout. Any overhead in interrupt response, function return, and scheduling induces a “quality of implementation” delay, expressed as duration `Di`. Ideally, this delay would be zero. Further, any contention for processor and memory resources induces a “quality of management” delay, expressed as duration `Dm`. The delay durations may vary from timeout to timeout, but in all cases shorter is better.
> 3. The functions whose names end in _­for take an argument that specifies a duration. These functions produce relative timeouts. Implementations should use a steady clock to measure time for these functions.326 Given a duration argument `Dt`, the real-time duration of the timeout is `Dt+Di+Dm`.

Which talks about the extra added time there may be added to the timeout before the function actually returns.

Answer (score 1):

You are working in a preemptive multithreading environment; *nothing* happens "immediately". Once you give your timeslice over to the OS by blocking (or it steals your timeslice), you've given up control. The OS will unblock your thread at some point after the mutex is unlocked. OS's try to be prompt about these things, but there are no guarantees.

The best you can hope for is "soon after". `wait_for` will get you that.